# option clash for package xcolor

Tags: color, captions

I'm trying to set some color on my caption like this

```
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[labelfont={color=red,bf}]{caption}
```

But it gives me this error "option clash for package xcolor". But then I look in the live preview it's does indeed to it. What am I doing wrong?
This is the hole preample

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[lmargin=25mm,rmargin=20mm,tmargin=20mm,bmargin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx} % support the \includegraphics command and options
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lastpage} % for the number of the last page in the document
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[labelfont={color=red,bf}]{caption}

\newcommand{\soa}{The Soma Project}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\newcommand\Signature[4]{\par\bigskip
\newcommand{\asp}{ASP.NET }
\newcommand{\aspm}{ASP.Net MVC 3}
\newcommand{\nh}{Nhibernate }

  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \begin{tabular}{@{\hspace{.05\textwidth}}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.4\textwidth}
      @{\hspace*{.1\textwidth}}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.4\textwidth}@{\hspace{.05\textwidth}}}
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{#1, \today} \\[10ex]
  \rule{.4\textwidth}{0.4pt} & \rule{.4\textwidth}{0.4pt} \\
  #2 & #3 \\[10ex]
\end{tabular}
\par
}% for example, change the margins to 2 inches all roundhh

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor =black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor  =black
}

\lstset{literate=%
{æ}{{\ae}}1
{å}{{\aa}}1
{ø}{{\o}}1
{Æ}{{\AE}}1
{Å}{{\AA}}1
{Ø}{{\O}}1
}


\pagestyle{fancy}

\lstset{extendedchars=\true}
\lstset{inputencoding=ansinew}

\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\leftmark}

%\lhead{Morten Starck \& Steffan Jensen}
\rhead{Section \thesection}
%\lfoot{\today}
\rfoot{Page \thepage\ af \pageref{LastPage}}
%\cfoot{\leftmark}
\usepackage{multirow}

\geometry{a4paper}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\definecolor{listinggray}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{lbcolor}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\lstset{
    backgroundcolor=\color{lbcolor},
    tabsize=4,
    rulecolor=,
    language=matlab,
        basicstyle=\scriptsize,
        upquote=true,
        aboveskip={1.5\baselineskip},
        columns=fixed,
        showstringspaces=false,
        extendedchars=true,
        breaklines=true,
        prebreak = \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
        frame=single,
        showtabs=false,
        showspaces=false,
        showstringspaces=false,
        identifierstyle=\ttfamily,
        keywordstyle=\color[rgb]{0,0,1},
        commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.133,0.545,0.133},
        stringstyle=\color[rgb]{0.627,0.126,0.941},
}

\lstdefinelanguage{CSharp}
{
 morecomment = [l]{//}, 
 morecomment = [l]{///},
 morecomment = [s]{/*}{*/},
 morestring=[b]", 
 sensitive = true,
 morekeywords = {abstract,  event,  new,  struct,
   as,  explicit,  null,  switch,
   base,  extern,  object,  this,
   bool,  false,  operator,  throw,
   break,  finally,  out,  true,
   byte,  fixed,  override,  try,
   case,  float,  params,  typeof,
   catch,  for,  private,  uint,
   char,  foreach,  protected,  ulong,
   checked,  goto,  public,  unchecked,
   class,  if,  readonly,  unsafe,
   const,  implicit,  ref,  ushort,
   continue,  in,  return,  using,
   decimal,  int,  sbyte,  virtual,
   default,  interface,  sealed,  volatile,
   delegate,  internal,  short,  void,
   do,  is,  sizeof,  while,
   double,  lock,  stackalloc,   
   else,  long,  static,   
   enum,  namespace,  string}
}

\hypersetup{pdfauthor={Morten T. Starck \& Steffan Jensen},
pdftitle={\soa},
pdfsubject={Afsluttende Bachelor Projekt PBA2011},
pdfkeywords={Dette er under copy right 2012 fra Morten Starck \& Steffan Jensen. Samt Virtual Lab APs.},
pdfproducer={Morten Starck \& Steffan Jensen \today},
pdfcreator={pdflatex, \LaTeX}]{hyperref}}

\usepackage[section]{placeins}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing more about your preamble. The error is caused by another package (or class) loading `xcolor` with different options. Are you using `beamer`?

Comment: I have just added the hole thing. For some reason i cant get it to display the hole thing as code block :(

Comment: You should provide more information about what other packages you are including. BTW, adding `\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}` before `\documentclass{...}` may be helpful. You have to remove `\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}` from the preamble.

Comment: You might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `xcolor` package is loaded by `listings`. Put the line before `\usepackage{listings}`.

However your preamble is quite messy. It's most important that you call `hyperref` as the last package and put all options to `geometry` before `fancyhdr`.

The package `ucs` is useless with your settings.

Comment: I no that it's abit messy. But the problem is that i have added new things along the way and it has been put in radom :( . But it now works. Thanks

Comment: Like Harish wrote `\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}` before the line `\usepackage{listings}` is fine and the problem is the same with TikZ. With `\PassOptionsToPackage` you can avoid conflicts between options.