# Page orientation of a beamerposter

Tags: beamer, geometry, paper-size, beamerposter

To change the orientation of a `beamerposter` the following usual code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[size=a4]{beamerposter}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}                                                                                                                                                                            
\begin{document}
hey
\end{document}
```

will give the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package geometry.
```

Therefore I am forced to pass the options to the `geometry` package in the beginning with `\PassOptionsToPackage{landscape}{geometry}`

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{landscape}{geometry}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[size=a4]{beamerposter}
\begin{document}
hey
\end{document}
```

(see, for example, [option clash for package xcolor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57364/option-clash-for-package-xcolor))

However, the result is completely **opposite**. When the `portrait` option is provided the page is landscape and vice versa.

This can indeed be a source of confusion and misunderstanding! How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The orientation can be given as an option of the package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[size=a4,orientation=landscape]{beamerposter}

\begin{document}
hey
\end{document}
```

Comment: What was causing my problem?